# Updating salesforce Hybrid cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, salesforce, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a little new to Salesforce Hybrid Mobile application development.

I have a well running hybrid application.

But recently when uploading the APK to play store, play store gives an error

```
Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. The Alerts page has more information about how to resolve the issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.
```

After some analysis I found that my android platform version is `3.6.x` which might be the reason for rejection.

So I updated cordova android platform of my existing Salesforce Hybrid app using the following command.

```
cordova platform update android
```

After updating the version of android platform is `5.2.2`

Salesforce Mobile sdk guide says to reinstall the salesforce plugin

So,

```
cordova plugin remove com.salesforce
```

And then

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin
```

But, while re-adding the plugin it gives the following message

```
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 5.2.2, failed version requirement: 5.0.0
Skipping 'com.salesforce' for android
```

And again running the project in eclipse gives many errors.

Not able to pin point the specefic issue here.

Any help is appretiated.

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while upgrading Android platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410437/error-while-upgrading-android-platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update to `5.0.0` instead of `5.2.2` because Salesforce plugin is made to `5.0.0` version.

You can see that in the `plugin.xml` file, in the `engine` tag.

`<engines>
    <engine name="cordova-android" version="5.0.0" />
    <engine name="cordova-ios" version="4.2.0" />
  </engines>`